# How to stop Ajax append from removing text format (line breaks & spaces)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to embed a text document into an html page.

I used ajax to embed the text document, however, formatting has been removed.

*What can I do to keep the text document's format the same?*

```
<div class="notepad"></div>
<script>
$.ajax({
    async:false,
    url:"../almost.asm",
    success: function(data) 
    {
       $(".notepad").append(data);
    }
      });       
</script>
```

Comment: what format you are looking for in text document

Comment: I'm trying to keep the line breaks and spacing.

Comment: _“however, formatting has been removed”_ – no, it has not been “removed” – but simple line breaks and multiple spaces have no such _effect_ in “normal” HTML, but are condensed into one single white space (_basic_ HTML knowledge btw.). If you want to retain them, then either use an element like `pre` that honors those by default, or use the CSS `white-space` property on the element you’re outputting the data in.

Comment: Well good job man. Been thinking about this for awhile and I guess I overlooked the fact that I was appending text into an html.

Answer (score 0):

Try using dataType as HTML

```
<div class="notepad"></div>
<script>
$.ajax({
    async:false,
    url:"../almost.asm",
    dataType : "html",
    success: function(data) 
    {
       $(".notepad").append(data);
    }
      });
```